# Is there a way to rate a mobile app from within a website

Tags: mobile, app-store, rating, google-play

How can I create a website that allows user to directly rate an app in the Apple iOS AppStore or Google Play? If not, is there a way to tigger the new iOS6 Facebook Likes for that App?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to rate an app is through the App Store either on a device or via iTunes.